# Read only SQL Server 2005 permission but allow stored procedure view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, database-permissions

I have a SQL Server 2005 database and I need to be able to grant a user(someday a group) read only database permissions with the ability to view but not run or modify stored procedures across over a dozen databases. Is there a way to do this with the current database roles included with SQL Server 2005 or does the user have to be granted permissions on each individual stored procedure. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO [Domain\UserName] worked for me.